# SSL Certificate Binding fails - Access is denied

Tags: c#, ssl, ssl-certificate, port

I want to bind a certificate to the port **0.0.0.0:443**.
As parameters for this certificate i have created:

```
ICertificateBindingConfiguration config = new CertificateBindingConfiguration();

var ipPort = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0"), 443);

var certificateThumbprint = serverCert.X509Certificate.Thumbprint.ToLower();

var appId = Guid.Parse("2f6580e5-a11a-4350-8cc0-47e5e0ac33e6");
```

But when i execute this code:

```
config.Bind(new CertificateBinding(certificateThumbprint, StoreName.My, ipPort, appId));
```

I get an error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(0x80004005): Access is denied ...
```

I am not local admin in the machine i am executing it.  How could i resolve this problem by executing it as admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you do not have admin rights in you machine. You need to be sure that you have.  To check if you have admin rights you could use this sample of code:

```
static bool IsElevated => new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()).IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
```

You could just create a sample C# console app and use the line of code above.
You need to use this line of code: `using System.Security.Principal;`
If it works than it is better to saperate this functionality in another .exe file and create a method like the method below to execute it as Admin:

```
public static int RunProcessAsAdmin(string exeName, string parameters)
{
    try {
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = CurrentDirectory;
        startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(CurrentDirectory, exeName);
        startInfo.Verb = "runas";
        //MLHIDE
        startInfo.Arguments = parameters;
        startInfo.ErrorDialog = true;

        Process process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(startInfo);
        process.WaitForExit();
        return process.ExitCode;
    } catch (Win32Exception ex) {
        WriteLog(ex);
        switch (ex.NativeErrorCode) {
            case 1223:
                return ex.NativeErrorCode;
            default:
                return ErrorReturnInteger;
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        WriteLog(ex);
        return ErrorReturnInteger;
    }
}
```